# Using build-helper-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, xl-deploy, build-helper-maven-plugin

I have the pom.xml below.

I'd like to pass a `tag` property to my build, using this command:

`mvn clean package -Dtag=test`

It should split this property into two others, `my.group` an `my.version`, and then use it in a URI to build an XLDeploy package, using the `xldeploy-maven-plugin` (https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/).

My problem is that the `regex-properties` goal is actually doing the job, as I can see thanks to the `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run (default) @ myArtifactId ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] Displaying value of 'my.group' property
     [echo] [my.group] group/test
     [echo] Displaying value of 'my.version' property
     [echo] [my.version] test
```

But the command `grep fileUri target\deployit-working-dir\deployit-manifest.xml` show that the vars in Uri does not get replaced:

```
grep fileUri target\deployit-working-dir\deployit-manifest.xml
      <fileUri>http://mynexus.ur/service/local/repositories/my-repo/content/${my.group}/anArtefact/${my.version}/anArtefact-1.0.zip</fileUri>
```

The POM is the following file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <packaging>dar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>regex-properties</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>regex-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <regexPropertySettings>
                                <regexPropertySetting>
                                    <name>my.group</name>
                                    <value>group/${tag}</value>
                                    <regex>(asm-[0-9]+)-([0-9]+.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$</regex>
                                    <replacement>$1</replacement>
                                    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                                </regexPropertySetting>
                                <regexPropertySetting>
                                    <name>my.version</name>
                                    <value>${tag}</value>
                                    <regex>(asm-[0-9]+)-([0-9]+.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$</regex>
                                    <replacement>$1-SNAPSHOT</replacement>
                                    <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                                </regexPropertySetting>
                            </regexPropertySettings>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Displaying value of 'my.group' property</echo>
                                <echo>[my.group] ${my.group}</echo>
                                <echo>Displaying value of 'my.version' property</echo>
                                <echo>[my.version] ${my.version}</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.xebialabs.xldeploy</groupId>
                <artifactId>xldeploy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0</version>

                <extensions>true</extensions>

                <configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <file.Folder name="file">
                            <scanPlaceholders>false</scanPlaceholders>
                            <fileUri>http://mynexus.ur/service/local/repositories/my-repo/content/${my.group}/anArtefact/${my.version}/anArtefact-${project.version}.zip</fileUri>
                        </file.Folder>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm not quite sure if the `build-helper-maven-plugin` wrong, or anywhere else in my POM, or if it's simply lack of replacing properties in the `xldeploy-maven-plugin`...

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source of xldeploy-maven-plugin-6.0.1, and it seems it is the limitation of the current implementation.

The problem is that `GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo` does not rely on maven to do the substitution of the properties. Instead, it uses a custom `AbstractConfigurationConverter` named `DeployitCIConverter` (which delegates to `MavenDeployableConverter`) to convert the `<deployables>` node to a list of `MavenDeployable`)

This boils down to:

- you have the access to effective POM
- you don't have access to properties defined dynamically via build helper plugin

Of course the properties defined dynamically can be acessed in any mojo:

- if you use a parameter
- if you evaluate them manually via expression evaluator (check: [get mojo parameters in maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823602/get-mojo-parameters-in-maven-plugin))

For the antrun plugin, it uses `ExpressionEvaluator` explicitely in the echo task.
Informative article:
[Properties resolution in Maven and its implications on Antrun plugin](https://technotes.khitrenovich.com/properties-resolution-maven-implications-antrun-plugin/)

**Ideas to fix the problem:**

- do your group and version parsing in external script and pass the values to mvn command.
- create a cutom mojo extending `GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo` and preprocess deployables in the execute method (not that hard as it sounds).

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed and accurate answer ;)
Unfortunately i have not been able to succeed in writing a new mojo extending GenerateDeploymentPackageMojo, i feel that not having the sources, and being a noob in maven plugins does not help... i'll try again later.

Comment: In fact, I don't have the sources either, but IDEs do a great job these days